# doxygen extern variables indexing

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I just started to use doxygen and may not be familiar with all available settings. I looked into all tags and options in configuration file, but havent been able to locate any relevant tag for the operation.

Is there any way to force doxygen to index externals in C/C++ ? Now they just plainly added to list of other variables in the source file.

EDIT: From what I have seen so far, is that doxygen doesnt understand the externals at all. It generates a references in html files for these variables or functions to random  ( first seen ) locations

Comment: Under Files -> File Members -> Variables I get all of my externals variables. This is in addition to their listing in each filename under Files -> File List.  I used EXTRACT_ALL = YES but I'm not sure if that specific directive is what does it.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking for. Are you talking about global variables? Are you looking for declarations, or usage of global variables? Please clarify.

Comment: @doxygen if the software is writen by you - big thanks. Now, yes, I am referring to global variables accessible from other files. If they dont contain any comments, they are hard to distinguish from other variables. Could there be a separate group by default for externals? Or prepent a bold word external (defined in ...) near each of the variables AND functions. Now everything just lies in a big heap. Of course, if you add comments near external definitions they appear in documentation, but again - its really not clear at first hand to understand that real definition is elsewhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local variables with file-only scope are marked as static, right? So when setting EXTRACT_STATIC to NO you won't see them at all.

That said: there is now no clear distinction between static and external variables in the index. I have plans to redesign the indexes to make them more interactive and then I will take your wish along (i.e. be able to filter on static v.s. external). If you want to be notified on when this happens please file a bug report with severity set to enhancement in doxygen's bug tracker.